# ggplotly - add line to existing plot (shiny)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I would like to let the user add a second line to an already existing plot or remove it if necessary without redrawing the whole plot. Alas I don't know how to do that or if that's even possible with `ggplotly`. Is there a package which lets you do that?

**ui.r**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(

    position = "left",

    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("fund", label = NULL, selected = "", choices = c('', LETTERS[1:6]), options = list(placeholder = "Choose something"), width = "350px"),
      selectizeInput("benchmark", label = NULL, selected = "", choices = c('', NULL, letters[1:6]), options = list(placeholder = "Choose something"), width = "350px"),
      verbatimTextOutput("hover")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("tsplot")
    )


  )
))
```

**server.r**

```
require(ggplot2)
require(plotly)
require(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # output$fundid <- renderText({
  #   print(input$fund)
  # })

  PFobj <- reactive({

    pf <- input$fund
    ts_info <- list(a = "x", b = "y")
    ts_data <- data.frame(Dat = seq(Sys.Date() - 200, Sys.Date(), 1), Val = cumsum(c(100, rnorm(200))))

    list(pf = pf, nav = ts_info, data = ts_data)

  })

  # Main plot
  observe({
    if(input$fund != '') {
      output$tsplot <- renderPlotly({
        p <- ggplot(PFobj()$data, aes(x = Dat, y = Val, group = 1, text = paste("</br>Date: ", Dat, "</br>Value: ", Val))) +
          geom_line(colour = "red")
        p <- ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text"), type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>% config(displayModeBar = F)
        p
      })
    }
  })

  # This should be updating the plot
  observe({
    if(input$benchmark != '') {
      output$tsplot <- renderPlotly({
        data <- PFobj()$data
        # p + geom_line(data, aes(x = Dat, y = Val, group = 1, text = paste("</br>Date: ", Dat, "</br>Value: ", Val)), colour = "black")
        # p %>% add_lines(x = data[,1], y = data[,2], color = "red")
      })
    }
  })

  output$hover <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_hover")
    if (!is.null(d)) {print(d); b <<- d$x}
  })

})
```

Comment: I doubt it's possible with `ggplot`. Though you can probably do so with standard `plot()` from R, as you build it step by step, unlike the `ggplot`. but it looks bad compared to what `ggplot` gives you

Comment: You could store `p <- ggplot(...) + ...` and output `gp <- ggplotly(p)`. If you need to draw a line, `p1 <- p + geom_line(...)` and redraw `gp1 <- ggplotly(p1)`. If you want to remove the line, you still have `p` and `gp` at hand.

Comment: @tonytonov Yes, that's what I am doing right now.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve exactly the same, looks like with `plotlyProxy` can be done but still haven't managed to do it.